# How to access the value calculated in one window to another window in python tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x

***I am trying to deeal with multiple windows where I am trying to import the salary calculated in the Wages class in the second window to the third window and display it in a label or entry box.***

```
from tkinter import *
class Welcome:
    def __init__(self,master,controller):
        self.master=master
        self.master.geometry('400x200+100+200')
        self.master.title('Welcome')
        self.controller=controller
        self.label1=Label(self.master,text='welcome to the wages calculator GUI',fg='red').grid(row=0,column=2)
        self.button1=Button(self.master,text='ok',fg='blue',command=self.gotowages).grid(row=6,column=2)
        self.button1=Button(self.master,text='quit',fg='blue',command=self.finish).grid(row=6,column=3)

    def gotowages(self):
        root2=Toplevel(self.master,self.controller)
        myGui=Wages(root2)
    def finish(self):
        self.master.destroy()


class Wages(Welcome):
    def __init__(self,master,controller):        
        self.mhours=DoubleVar()
        self.salaryh=DoubleVar()        
        self.master=master
        self.controller=controller
        self.master.geometry('500x200+100+200')
        self.master.title("Wages Calculator")
        self.label1=Label(self.master,text="welcome to salary calculator",fg='red').grid(row=0,column=2)
        self.label2=Label(self.master,text='Enetr your salary per hour').grid(row=3,column=0)
        self.label3=Label(self.master,text='Enter number of hours worked').grid(row=4,column=0)
        self.mysalary=Entry(self.master,textvar=self.salaryh).grid(row=3,column=2)
        self.myhours=Entry(self.master,textvar=self.mhours).grid(row=4,column=2)
        self.button1=Button(self.master,text='calculatesalary',fg='blue',command=self.calculatesalary).grid(row=5,column=2)
        self.button2=Button(self.master,text='Back',fg='blue',command=self.quit).grid(row=5,column=3)
        self.button3=Button(self.master,text='page3',fg='blue',command=self.page3).grid(row=5,column=4)

    def calculatesalary(self):
        hours=self.mhours.get()
        print (hours)
        hsal=self.salaryh.get()
        salary=hours*hsal
        print (salary)
        state="your salary is "+str(salary)
        self.labelresult=Label(self.master,text=state).grid(row=7,column=2)
        self.controller.value=state
    def page3(self):
        root3=Toplevel(self.master)
        myPage=Page(root3)    
    def quit(self):
        self.master.destroy()

#---------------------------
class Page(Wages):
        def __init__(self,master,contoller):
            self.master=master
            self.controller=controller
            self.master.geometry('500x200+100+200')
            self.master.title("trial page")
            self.label1=Label(self.master,text=self.controller,fg='red').grid(row=0,column=2)
            self.label2=Label(self.master,text="bibhu prasanna behera",fg='red').grid(row=0,column=3)
            self.button3=Button(self.master,text='page3',fg='blue',command=self.quit).grid(row=5,column=4)
        def quit(self):
            self.master.destroy()

def main():
     root=Tk()
     myGuiWelcome=Welcome(root,"ll")
     root.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

***I want to access salary calculated in the Wages class on the next page as a label as a trial.***

Answer (score 0):

I included Wages.**init**(self,*args,**kwargs) to access the values but failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
class Welcome:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        self.master.geometry('400x200+100+200')
        self.master.title('Welcome')        
        self.label1=Label(self.master,text='welcome to the wages calculator GUI',fg='red').grid(row=0,column=2)
        self.button1=Button(self.master,text='ok',fg='blue',command=self.gotowages).grid(row=6,column=2)
        self.button1=Button(self.master,text='quit',fg='blue',command=self.finish).grid(row=6,column=3)
        
    def gotowages(self):
        root2=Toplevel(self.master)
        myGui=Wages(root2)
    def finish(self):
        self.master.destroy()
        
state=''
class Wages(Welcome):
    def __init__(self,master):
        #Welcome.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.mhours=DoubleVar()
        self.salaryh=DoubleVar()        
        self.master=master
        #self.salary=salary
        self.master.geometry('500x200+100+200')
        self.master.title("Wages Calculator")
        self.label1=Label(self.master,text="welcome to salary calculator",fg='red').grid(row=0,column=2)
        self.label2=Label(self.master,text='Enetr your salary per hour').grid(row=3,column=0)
        self.label3=Label(self.master,text='Enter number of hours worked').grid(row=4,column=0)
        self.mysalary=Entry(self.master,textvar=self.salaryh).grid(row=3,column=2)
        self.myhours=Entry(self.master,textvar=self.mhours).grid(row=4,column=2)
        self.button1=Button(self.master,text='calculatesalary',fg='blue',command=self.calculatesalary).grid(row=5,column=2)
        self.button2=Button(self.master,text='Back',fg='blue',command=self.quit).grid(row=5,column=3)
        self.button3=Button(self.master,text='page3',fg='blue',command=self.page3).grid(row=5,column=4)
        
    def calculatesalary(self):
        global state
        hours=self.mhours.get()
        #print (hours)
        hsal=self.salaryh.get()
        salary=hours*hsal
        print (salary)
        state="your salary is "+str(salary)
        self.labelresult=Label(self.master,text=state).grid(row=7,column=2)
        #return state
    def page3(self):
        root3=Toplevel(self.master)
        myPage=Page(root3)
        print (state)
        
    def quit(self):
        self.master.destroy()
        
#---------------------------
class Page(Wages):
        def __init__(self,master):            
            self.equation=StringVar()
            self.master=master
            self.master.geometry('500x200+100+200')
            self.master.title("trial page")
            self.label1=Label(self.master,text="bibhu",fg='red').grid(row=0,column=2)
            self.label2=Label(self.master,text="bibhu prasanna behera",fg='red').grid(row=0,column=3)
            self.button3=Button(self.master,text='back',fg='blue',command=self.quit).grid(row=5,column=4)
            self.entry1=Entry(self.master,textvar=self.equation,fg='red').grid(row=3,column=3)
            self.equation.set(state)
            self.button4=Button(self.master,text='display',fg='blue',command=self.display).grid(row=7,column=4)
        def quit(self):
            self.master.destroy()
        def display(self):
            self.label3=Label(self.master,text=self.equation.get(),fg='blue').grid(row=9,column=3)
            
        
def main():
     root=Tk()
     myGuiWelcome=Welcome(root)
     root.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

I solved the issue by adding a global variable.